# Grab all args in bash script while only needing specific string for case

Tags: bash, case, args

I have a bash script called manp that has a few case options as follows:

```
ARGS=$@

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
    case "$1" in
        --log)
            LOG=1
            shift
            ;;
        --upgrade*)
            UPGRADE=1
            echo "$ARGS"              # Outputs --upgrade tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2
            PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#*\ }    # Supposed to strip everything before the space in front of tclclean
            shift
            ;;
        -*|*) 
            echo "Unknown command '$ARGS'"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ ! -z "$UPGRADE" ]; then
    echo "$PCKG_INFO"
    exit 0
fi
```

What I'm trying to do is run `$ manp --upgrade tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2`
and get the `--upgrade` case to start, while putting `tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2` into the PCKG_INFO variable

When I run that command, I get both `--upgrade` and `*|*` case and this is the output:

```
--upgrade tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2    # Output of echo ARGS

 Unknown command '--upgrade tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2'    # Output of echo PCKG_INFO
```

So the problem is that it runs both cases and `PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#*\ }` doesn't strip anything...
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you imagine `${ARGS#*^ $}` means? There is no match on the glob expression `*^ $` so nothing is removed.

Comment: @tripleee Oh sorry I made a mistake, it's supposed to be `${ARGS#*\ }`

Comment: `case "$@" in` is very odd. I cannot imagine how having *every* argument in the case statement is what you want there. Did you mean `case "$1" in` (given that you are `shitft`ing arguments off as you consume them)?

Comment: If `upgrade` isn't actually optional, it simply shouldn't be an option, and you could merely `echo "$@"` in the final `if` (which I imagine isn't your real code, but just a placeholder for something more complex and possibly more sinister).

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried using `case "$1"` to only look at the `--upgrade` but it gives the same output.
@tripleee Yea the final if is missing a lot of codebut it needs the ARGS minus the --upgrade to work

Comment: You need to shift *every* argument you consume when you consume them. Your problem is that you are looping over every argument (even the *values* to the arguments. Stop printing `$ARGS` in the cases and print `$1` instead and you'll see what is happening. Also don't stuff an array (`$@`) into a string (`$ARGS`) if you expect to need individual "words" again because you can't get them back.

Comment: If you know that *every* argument after `--upgrade` is going to be what you need later (and there can't be any other arguments) then you can simplify things here. If you don't know that and still want an unbounded amount of arguments after `--upgrade` and before the next argument then you get to have a "state machine" in your `while`/`case` loop keeping track of the last `-*` argument you got and doing the right thing with non-option arguments as you see them.

Comment: @EtanReisner I ended up finding a pretty simple solution actually (I'm not sure if  it's very nice code but it works). Instead of shifting, since I know `--upgrade` is going to be the only necessary argument, I can just break out of the case statement and continue on with the code. Both `PCKG_INFO` and `UPGRADE` have been initialized and have the right value (I used `${ARGS#*\ }` for the stripping) and there's no need for the other case statements so a break is perfect.

Comment: `ARGS=$@` is a mistake and only a mistake. If you need a single string argument of everything in `$@` post-`shift`ing `--upgrade` away then you want `$*`/`"$*"` at that point. But if you have something that works write it up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Seriously, search for getopts, switch to it, and save yourself a lot of trouble.  You have so many mistakes here, and this is a poor forum to teach.  It'd be easier if one of us was standing behind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your shift is only removing the one case'd argument. The subsequent arguments you are putting in PCKG_INFO are still on the command line. The next iteration of the loop will start with the argument "tclclean==2.21". So for each argument you are putting into PCKG_INFO you also need to shift for. Also, that `PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#*\ }` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't *change* the contents of ARGS. It just *returns* that substring of ARGS. ARGS remains unchanged (except for the *shift*ing going on).

Now if you know exactly how many arguments after the --upgrade you're going to want, then you can just do that many shifts (or even `shift 3`). If you can guarantee that the --upgrade with its arguments will be the last things on the line, then you can just shift the switch argument first, and then make PCKG_INFO=$ARGS. But if you can't ensure either of those things, you're going to need to find a way to determine when you're done with PCKG_INFO args, and that's going to require an inner loop, where you iterate over the subsequent arguments (again, `shift`ing each one) until you reach the termination marker, then resume with the outer `case` loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know why you aren't just using getopts?

```
ARGS=" tclclean==2.1 pms ubu==2.2"
PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#*^ $}      # Supposed to strip everything before the space in front of tclclean
```

should be

`PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#* }`

However, casing $@ and shifting seems wrong.  You should switch to getopts

Comment: I tried `PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#* }` already but it doesn't work either, and I'm pretty new to shell scripting so I never heard of getopts

Comment: Unless you are leaving something out, I don't see anywhere where you are assigning ARGS, so .... you have nothing to work with.  Search the web for a getopts tutorial, and convert to useing it.  The variable masking I put up works if you get ARGS assigned to the part you want.

Comment: IMNSHO `getopts` doesn't actually provide any benefit over `while case shift` as the code complexity and maintainability is pretty much identical for both approaches. But the OP's code is not a successful example of the latter.

Comment: @SaintHax Sorry, I forgot to add it at the top but `ARGS=$@`

Comment: @triplee IMO, his whole technique is wrong and you can find tutorials on how to do this with getopts.  In addition, you don't have to custom code all your shifts and error handling for missing args for switches that require an argument.  Actually, that just makes it easier and better, in addition to the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to prevent going into both cases by breaking out of the `--upgrade` case since it leaves the entire loop without iterating through the other arguments in the command.

```
--upgrade*)
    UPGRADE=1
    echo "$ARGS"              
    PCKG_INFO=${ARGS#*\ }    
    break
    ;;
```